# How do I get Beautifulsoup to Parse a Serial HTML list in a table into a CSV pattern of data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I have an internal company webpage that lists a variety of data in a long list that I want to convert into a CSV file for reviewing.  The data is in the format of:

```
*CUSTOMER_1*
Email Link   Category_Text    Phone_Numbers
Email Link   Category_Text    Phone_Numbers
*Customer_2*
Email Link   Category_Text    Phone_Numbers
Email Link   Category_Text    Phone_Numbers
```

Encoded in HTML it looks like

```
<table id="responsibility">
    <tr class="customer">
        <td colspan="6">
            <strong>CUSTOMER 1</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_1" title="Role_Name1">
        <td><a href="email@company.com1">Name_1</a></td>
        <td>Category_Text</td>
        <td>Phone_Numbers</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2" title="Role_Name2">
        <td><a href="email@company.com2">Name_2</a></td>
        <td>Category_Text</td>
        <td>Phone_Numbers</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer">
        <td colspan="6">
            <strong>CUSTOMER 2</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_1" title="Role_Name1">
        <td><a href="email@company.com3">Name_3</a></td>
        <td>Category_Text</td>
        <td>Phone_Numbers</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2" title="Role_Name2">
        <td><a href="email@company.com2">Name_2</a></td>
        <td>Category_Text</td>
        <td>Phone_Numbers</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to end up with a file.csv that contains the info in this fashion

```
   CUSTOMER1,Role_Name1,Name_1,Email_1,Category_Text,Phone_Numbers
   CUSTOMER1,Role_Name2,Name_2,Email_2,Category_Text,Phone_Numbers
   CUSTOMER2,Role_Name1,Name_3,Email_3,Category_Text,Phone_Numbers
   CUSTOMER2,Role_Name1,Name_2,Email_2,Category_Text,Phone_Numbers
```

Right now i can get a list of all of the Customer names or a list of all of the text but I haven't been able to figure out how to iterate over every customer and then iterate over every line for each customer

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("source.html"), "html.parser")

with open("output.csv",'w') as file:
    responsibility=soup.find('table',{'id':'responsibility'})
    line=responsibility.tr
    for i in responsibility:
        print(line)
        line=responsibility.tr.next_sibling
```

I was expecting this to print every  tag in the document but instead it only prints the first and never cycles to the next  tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on this line of code :

```
line=responsibility.tr
```

Here, you are using `.tr` tag, which locates the first instance of `<tr>` tag block and returns it's contents.

What does it mean over here?
Let's just say you have *n* instances of `<tr>` tag, then using `.tr` will give you only the first instance among those *n* `<tr>` instances as a result. So, if you wish to extract all *n* of them, then use **find_all()**. It will return a list of all possible matches.

```
line=responsibility.find_all("tr", class_="customer")
```

Also, add the `class_="customer"` filter. It will help you to locate all the `<tr>` blocks with the "customer" class. Then simply using the **.next_sibling** will allow you to find the 2 subsequent rows with `title="Role_Name*"` attribute.

So, to put the above theory in practice, watch this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("source.html"), "html.parser")

with open("output.csv",'w') as file:
    responsibility=soup.find('table',{'id':'responsibility'})
    lines=responsibility.find_all("tr", class_ = "customer")
    for i in responsibility:
        for line in lines:
            line1=line.next_sibling              #locates tr with title="Role_Name1"
            line2=line.next_sibling.next_sibling #locates tr with title="Role_Name2"
            print(line1)
            print(line2)
```